# Python : ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: python, bash, numpy, pip

I am trying to run the bash script and i am repeatedly incurring following error

```
File "/usr/share/fsl/5.0/bin/aff2rigid", line 75, in <module>
    from numpy import *
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have installed latest version of Numpy

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
python-numpy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
```

I do not understand why this error repeats when i have already installed the latest version of Numpy.

kindly let me know if there is something i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except installing python-numpy library you have to install numpy with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) or [easy_install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions), one of commands below:

```
# install numpy with pip
pip install numpy

# install numpy with easy_install
easy_install numpy
```

Comment: Following is the error i am getting              error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-30804.write-test'

Comment: I did the same as you suggested and this is the output               ------                                            dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up

Comment: run `sudo pip uninstall numpy`, after run `sudo pip install numpy`, then start python interpreter  and try `import numpy`

Comment: I have done what you have suggested and this is the reply ------------dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo pip uninstall numpy
Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS

Comment: what about starting python  and importing numpy within interpreter ?

Comment: I have tried that and i am getting same error ,Actually i am running FSL Pipeline and the Pipeline imports numpy for image processing work , but somehow i am facing problems

Comment: very strange, you should be able to work with numpy... do you have numpy listed in packages after running `pip freeze` ? might be you have to restart your OS ( not sure about that, but it might help ... )

Comment: When i checked it it says ----------dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ pip freeze
numpy==1.8.2

Comment: That's rare , try to run `pip install numpy --user` and make sure that `~/.local/bin` is in the $PATH

Comment: Now when i done that i am getting following response -------dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/usr/local$ pip install numpy --user
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: does `~/.local/bin` in $PATH environment  variable?

Comment: No its not an environmental variable

Comment: see section "Setting path at Unix/Linux
" of  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm article

Comment: I have verified about python version and installation  and this is what i got when i tried to open python terminal------------                      dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/usr/local$ python
Python 2.7.9 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:33:51) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

Comment: See that article, here is steps for installin numpy and other packages via anaconda http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/blog/installation-of-python-spyder-numpy-sympy-scipy-pytest-matplotlib-via-anaconda.html